# Can't Style Grommet icon inside Anchor

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, grommet

I'm new to Grommet with styled components.
I Have already checked all the docs and can't find the solution.

PROBLEM

I have an Anchor with an icon and a label.
Problem is I cannot target the icon for styling when i hover or it is active.
Text / Label changes the styling though. How can i achieve/fix this?

I've also tried using styled components and putting an Icon and a Text inside a Grommet Box, but didn't work.

Please help!

```
import React from "react";
import { Anchor, Box, Text } from "grommet";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Currency as PayoutIcon, Menu as MenuIcon } from "grommet-icons";

const StyledAnchor = styled(Anchor)`
  display: flex;
  height: 56px;
  color: #808191;
  padding: px 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: transparent;
  width: max-content;

  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Inter;
  color: #808191;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all 0.25s ease 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;

  &:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: #6c5dd3;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  &:active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6c5dd3;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }

  &:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6c5dd3;
    textdecoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
`;
const SidebarItem = () => {
  return (
    // <Box color="#808191" hoverIndicator="true">
    <StyledAnchor
      color="#808191"
      label="Payouts"
      onClick={() => {}}
      href="#"
      icon={<PayoutIcon />}
    />
    // </Box>
  );
};

export default SidebarItem;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the granularity of styles you are looking for, I think you can directly use the Button component instead of Anchor, nevertheless, the usage of Button is more compliant with accessibility standards (WCAG) for the Sidebar interactive elements that you are describing above.

Grommet works best with styled-components, yet grommet theme-ing is also very powerful, and knowing how to leverage its capabilities will help you use styled-components much less.
Recently, grommet extended the Button theme (kind/default button), and that should do the trick for you with no sweat and no need for styled-components, here is an example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Box, Grommet, Button } from "grommet";
import { Currency as PayoutIcon } from "grommet-icons";

const theme = {
  global: {
    colors: {
      myColor: "#808191",
      "background-contrast": {
        dark: "#FFFFFF14",
        light: "#0000000A"
      },
      "active-background": "background-contrast",
      "active-text": "red",
      icon: "text",
      // focus color is an important indication for keyboard navigation accessibility, 
      // it will be an ill advice to set it to undefined and remove focus 
      focus: "teal",
      text: {
        dark: "#C0CADC",
        light: "#444444"
      }
    }
  },
  button: {
    default: {
      color: "#808191",
      border: undefined,
      font: {
        weight: 700
      },
      padding: {
        horizontal: "12px",
        vertical: "6px"
      }
    },
    hover: {
      default: {
        background: {
          color: "background-contrast"
        },
        color: "brand"
      },
      secondary: {
        border: {
          width: "3px"
        },
        padding: {
          horizontal: "9px",
          vertical: "3px"
        }
      }
    },
    active: {
      background: {
        color: "aliceblue"
      },
      color: "teal",
      secondary: {
        border: {
          color: "transparent"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const SidebarItem = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();
  return (
    <Button
      active={active}
      label="Payouts"
      icon={<PayoutIcon />}
      onClick={() => {
        setActive(!active);
      }}
      href="#"
    />
  );
};

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Grommet theme={theme}>
      <Box pad="small" align="start">
        <SidebarItem />
      </Box>
    </Grommet>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/grommet-themed-button-36g5r?file=/index.js:0-1866) for running it live.

The Button has the granularity for active/hover/disabled and more, you can basically gain the same functionality in Anchor using the theme `anchor.extend` but this way is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Hello Shimi. Thanks a lot for your response and for helping out. 1) What does the "option" key means in the theme object? Is it another type of button as "default" or "primary"? cant find info in the button docs 2)  I'm still not beeing able to remove border when i click on the button ("active" or "focus") nor to change the backround-color when button is "active" or "focus".Could you please help me understand this? cant find a focus or onfocus for the button. How can I make a background of an specific color when clicking or after? when button is focus. Cant understand how to edit it in theme

Comment: The example you sent me in sandbox does nothing when the button is cliecked("active") or "focus" (how it remains after clicking). Can't figure it out yet

Comment: 1) I've cleaned up the `option` from the example. 2) The `border` you brought up is the generic behavior to mark an interactive element that is being focused, and hence should help users with an accessibility need such as keyboard navigation. It's a web standard of WCAG and it's recommended to keep it. That being said, you can control the focus color to `undefined` (or any other color) on the theme's `global.colors.focus` as you can see in the code example. 
You can make a button with a specific color using active, you just need an active state, I fixed the example to demonstrate it better.

Comment: Hello Shimi. thanks again for your time. I understand about the outline,etc. Anbout the focus what I was trying to achieve is working with focus wiith specific element, not with the global focus. Let's say for instance. Apply some style to a Button or Anchor that is currently on focus, and not to other element types. Sorry I didnt make myself clear. I discovered today that the best way to target this would be with the use ofd the extend key in the element we want to target in the theme (outside of the "global" object of the theme. /thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I think that your intentions are more towards the `active` state rather than the `focus`. So in this case it is fairly easy, the `extend` prop on the `button.active` theme should help you to set any CSS style you desire. For example, the `button.active` doesn't have an entry for padding, so this property could be easily styled with the `extend` option by adding `extend: 'padding: 40px;' for example` to `button.active`. I added it to the sandbox so you can take a look, you were on the right track with the `extend` direction, I hope this answer helps.

Comment: Thanks again shimi. Another question I have about Grommet in general. Is it possible to create a Button class when i create my own theme. Lets say i create "myTheme" based on Grommet's  "base" theme. Can I create for instance  a "mySpecialButton" like we have "primary" or "secondary" button in the theme?

Comment: It is not a documented behavior at the moment but it might work. My personal preference will be to keep the application simple, and ask myself whether I even need 4 types of frequent buttons (since you already have the default, primary, secondary and the new one you'll be interested in adding). I would try to work with those three existing types of buttons as my frequent buttons before adding more to the party. In some cases you'll need a 'one-time' button, and in this specific case, you don't need the theme, you can just leverage the children on button capabilities.